# Rendering components if class is present

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-directives

I need some help with a VUEJS project. I would like to render a component depending on whether a certain class is present.

### LOGIC

If (class a) is present render (component a)
If (class b) is present render (component b)
If neither (class a) or (class b) is present render neither

```
  <section class="card" v-if="">
      <h3>{{title}}</h3>
      <p>{{subtitle}}</p>
  </section>
```

Comment: Hi, when you say "present", do you mean instantiated in your components data, or do you mean something else that may not be clear?

Comment: @JTInfinite sorry, just to clarify- if the section has class a then render component a (within the section element). Hope thats clearer sorry :)

Comment: Ah sorry I was thinking javascript class. Doh. I think the provided answer is correct

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

Template:

```
<section class="card class-a class-b">
  <div v-if="isAPresent"></div>
  <div v-if="isBPresent"></div>
</section>
```

Just remove the `class-a` or `class-b` accordingly

Script:

```
computed: {
  isAExist () {
     return window.document.querySelector('section.class-a')
  },
  isBExist () {
     return window.document.querySelector('section.class-b')
  },
},
```

Comment: This worked for trying to do thank you! I didnt actually need components for it but I don't know if I can mark it as correct because the original question was to display components based on the classes.

Comment: Ah I get your question now, let me update my answer quickly